# Empty string as map key in Go?

Tags: string, dictionary, go

Is it a good or bad practice to store to store "" as a map key in Go? It seems like a special case which wouldnt be ideal for storage as a key. What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

The empty `string` value `""` is a valid value for the `string` type, so it's a valid key value for maps having `string` as the key type. There's nothing "edge" case in that.

Whether it makes sense to store a value associated with the empty string key really depends on your use case. There's nothing good or bad in it. Use it if it has meaning for you.

Comment: That's good to know. This is particularly useful for a map used to map strings to other values, where an unset string defaults to some value.